# FB Graph API: Any way to search through all posts?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way to search through the entire database of posts posted by a specific user (friend of logged-in user or logged-in user). According to the Graph API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api) one can search through a News Feed or Profile feed (Wall), but none of which refer to posts written a year ago.

Best regards :)

Comment: It's reasonable to think that they are no longer available. Facebook holds a lot of data.

Comment: @the_drow The search is more or less useless if it's limited in time/posts. Hope you are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and search your **own** posts by querying the [`stream`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) FQL table:

```
You can get two types of data when you query this table:

  * You can get public data (viewable to anyone on Facebook) without needing an extended permission.
  * You can get more data if you prompt the user for the read_stream extended permission.
```

How to search it depends on your needs and well documented in the link above.